# Drupal7 module that can be uploaded each folder

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is there a modules of Drupal7 that can be uploaded each folder?
I want to upload, while maintaining the hierarchy in the folder.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Core modules are in: /modules

Custom and contributed modules go in (generally): sites/all/modules

You can put whatever folders you like in here, for example it is quite common to have:

sites/all/modules/contrib
sites/all/modules/development
sites/all/modules/features

You can put whatever modules in whatever folders.

I'm not sure this answers your question? Please comment and I can update the answer, your question just isn't that clear to me so sorry if I am on the wrong track?

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I'm looking for a module.
The module's uploader.
It's rather than to upload a file, it's the ability to upload an entire folder.

Comment: Sorry really hard to understand you but I think I get it. Look at this:
https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload
However if I wanted to do that I would not use a module I would SCP myself.

Comment: Due to security constraints of the browser, my purpose is as difficult.
Thank you for your kindness.